# SQL custom grouping expression based on the field value string Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, grouping, bids

I am having a table in BIDS with three columns (e.g. Team, Product Name, Count).
For the Column Product name, I want to apply grouping, that will check for particular string "laptop" and sum all the Product Names containing string "laptop" under Laptops. Values in Product Name may vary, but there is a certain pattern like XX.Laptop.1, YY.Laptop.2 and mix of combinations to laptop.

I need something that will render full list, but add a group over Tablix Group with use of custom expression `=IIF(Fields!Product_Name.Value)LIKE "laptop", "Laptops")`

Please kindly advice. Thank you

Much thanks Alejandro! here is the result I got after applying your suggestion. 
[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cSpV.png)
I need two additional questions:

1. If there is a second group I would like to use for grouping - how to add it? (eg. desktops)
2. How to add a sumary value for the group? Shall it be done over exprerssion?

Thank you

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current code attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this expression for setting the group by `Product Name` and to show the `Product Name` in the respective cell.

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!Product_Name.Value,"laptop") > 0,"Laptops",Fields!Product_Name.Value)
```

If for a specific row the `Product Name` contains `laptop` it will group on "Laptops" otherwise it will group by the `Product Name` value for that row.

**UPDATE:** If you want to check for another word to create an additional group you can use:

```
=Switch(
InStr(Fields!Product_Name.Value,"laptop") > 0,"Laptop",
InStr(Fields!Product_Name.Value,"desktop") > 0,"Desktop",
true,Fields!Product_Name.Value
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I got almost successfull result

Comment: What is your problem now? Don't edit my answer to detail your problem, edit your question instead.

Comment: I realized I need some summary value for the group and there is another product family I would like to add

Comment: @Mario, check my update, If you want to add a new group value just add new conditional to the switch expression.

Comment: It is just almost perfect, but still missing count fro the grouped item. Can not do it with Row Group properties

Comment: to get the count just use `=Count(Fields!Product_Name.Value)`.